# How to close properly with aiozmq/zmq?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, pyzmq

I ran into this issue when my backend was not running.
You can find here a really simple demo to reproduce my case (you can reduce the timeout to 1 if you want to save some time testing) :

```python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import threading
import logging
import asyncio
from aiozmq import rpc

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

async def go():
    logging.debug('Go !')
    client = None
    try:
        client = await rpc.connect_rpc(connect='tcp://127.0.0.1:5555', timeout=5)
        await client.call.remote(1, 2)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
    finally:
        if client is not None:
            client.close()
            await client.wait_closed()

    logging.debug('done')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(go())
loop.close()

logging.debug(asyncio.Task.all_tasks())
logging.debug(threading.enumerate())
```

You will notice that both coro (`go` & the one we `wait_for`) are done and python only tracks the `MainThread`.
But you can see in top (`htop`) that your script has actually 2 thread running.

- 1 blocked on an `epoll_wait(10,`
- 1 looping on  :

  ```
  epoll_wait(13, [], 256, 168)            = 0
  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
  fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
  fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
  fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
  connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5555), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
  epoll_ctl(13, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {0, {u32=1275071824, u64=140476770422096}}) = 0
  epoll_ctl(13, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 3, {EPOLLOUT, {u32=1275071824, u64=140476770422096}}) = 0
  epoll_wait(13, [{EPOLLOUT|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP, {u32=1275071824, u64=140476770422096}}], 256, -1) = 1
  epoll_ctl(13, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 3, 0x7fc34c000d54) = 0
  getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [111], [4]) = 0
  close(3)                                = 0
  ```

I am not 100% sure, but I think the `EPOLLOUT|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP` that we receive is the HUP=HangUp=ConnectionRefused.

I tracked down the remaining/invisible threads to be somewhere in the zmq library.

Does anybody know what is happening and how to stop it properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this as an [issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiozmq/issues/125) on github and got the answer.

This is actually due to the [Linger period](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-setsockopt#toc15).

The solution is simply to add `client.transport.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)` right after the call to `connect_rpc`.

---

It may also be useful to add `loop.is_running()` in the `if` of the `finally` close to prevent any attempt in closing the socket if the loop is not running anymore (due to another exception for example).